# how to put a customizable button on the desktop?

Tags: windows-10, widgets

i use a lot of adobe illustrator. i use delete button the most.I am using windows.

**is there a way to create a floating customizable button like a widget or applet ?**

I would like to assign the "delete" function to it, if there were such a thing.

Comment: [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/)

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for this. It introduced me to a lot fun things to do. However, I can't find how to use it to create a "delete" button.

Comment: I didn't fully read your question's body and only glanced at the heading and bolded text; I've never used Rainmeter to create a delete button, but most OS functions can be coded into a Rainmeter widget config - try a [Bang](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/bangs/) coupled with an [Action](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/skins/option-types/#Action)